# wp7 popup blocking textbox in popup

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a popup that opens on the MainPage with a couple of textboxes. When ever you focus on the lower textbox the keyboard obscures it from view. Usually the textboxes slide into view. i don't know why that is not happening here.

please help!

```
<UserControl x:Class="Controls.EditControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:SampleData="clr-namespace:SampleData" 
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
Height="800" Width="480"
d:DataContext="{d:DesignData ../SampleData/sampleEditPopup.xaml}">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FF000000" Opacity="0.995">
    <StackPanel Margin="0,20,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="15,10,0,10" Width="110" TextAlignment="Right"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="tb_name" 
            TextWrapping="Wrap" 
            Width="340" Height="75"
            Margin="10,13,15,12"
            InputScope="Text" MaxLength="1000" 
            Text="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,150,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Description" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="15,40,0,10" Width="110" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Right"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="tb_description" 
            TextWrapping="Wrap" 
            Width="340" Height="254" 
            Margin="10,13,15,12"
            InputScope="Text" MaxLength="1000" 
            Text="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

and here is the code to open it:

```
EditControl ec = new EditControl();
ec.Title = cm.Title;
ec.Description = cm.Description;

//sets appbar icons for accepting values
setEditIcons();

Popup edit = new Popup() { Child = ec, Tag = this };
edit.Closed += new EventHandler(edit_Closed);
edit.IsOpen = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

from a UX perspective I'd heavily recommend against having any partial popup/overlay that has more than 1 or 2 buttons. It's just not done in WP7. If you have a form you'd like folks to fill out move it to its own page. Either by letting the user navigate to that page, or by introducing a new transient page (that cannot be navigated back into) prior to the current page.

You'll have more problems than just the on-screen keyboard in with form overlays. You'll need to change the AppBar to have "V" and "X" buttons for any data entry, you'll need to manage focus not slipping back into under the overlay/popup, you'll need to make sure the "back" button closes the popup, etc.

IMO The best approach is a simple and consistent UX.

Comment: I understand your point. But navigating to another page in order to change an object name and description seems like overkill. I have actually handled all of those other conditions already. If I navigate to another page then i have to worry about passing the objects and values needed to that page plus when i come back i have to make sure the right info is displayed. Maybe that's my only option but seems kind of ridiculous.

Comment: That's exactly what the People Hub does for renaming contacts, that's what office does, and that's what everything else does. If you're a developer please avoid "innovating" in Metro without giving something proper UX considerations. Unless you've grounded your opinion in the metro design language principles, strive for consistency with other apps and the OS. Users will downvote your app for failing to design a Metroesque app. Just my 0.02$.

Comment: I have been through the metro guidelines and also what I am doing is different from what the people hub and other apps do. I am not "innovating" anything I'm using a control that is built in. don't believe me? here is a clip from the guidelines "For transient UI, such as the login screen, you can use the Silverlight Popup control..." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202911%28v=vs.92%29.aspx ... anyway i was able to get the keyboard to work properly by creating in xaml instead of code behind.